# stored procedure to update data in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

I am newbie to sql. I am practicing on foreign key relationships by doing a small application. It have 3 tables. One table named ***"stpersonal"*** with cloumns as *stID, stname, stdateofbirth, stgender*. stID column is identity column and primary key column. As the student contain multiple fields in education, i used second table named ***"steducation"*** with fields *stID, stcollege, stgradyear*.
 *stID in steducation table has foreign key relation with stID in stpersonal table.*
 And third table ***"staddress"*** for student addresses with columns *stID, stAddress*.
*stID in staddress table has foreign key relation with stID in stpersonal table.*
 I got the stored procedure to get all student details and delete and insert. But I a unable to figure out stored procedure for update. I tried the following method to create stored procedure

```
 create procedure stupdate
    (
    @ID int,
    @stname nvarchar(50),
    @stdateofbirth nvarchar(50),
    @stgender nvarchar(50),
    @stcollege nvarchar(50),
    @stgradyear datetime,
    @stAddress nvarchar(50)
    )
    as begin
    update stpersonal
    set
    stname = @stname,
    stdateofbirth = @stdateofbirth,
    stgender = @stgender,
    stcollege = @stcollege,
    stgradyear = @stgradyear,
    stAddress = @stAddress
    where stpersonal.stID = @ID
    end
```

This is the code I tried. I tried to use joins, but nothing worked out. So i  hope I could  overcome this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: First you should only tag the DBMS you are using. mysql <> sql server. Then check out this article for a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Is this information about my question not clear?

Comment: No. I don't understand what the problem is. Posting the ddl for your tables would go a LONG way making this more clear.

Comment: @DotNetbeginner is mysql or sql server? do you have the ddl to show us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 UPDATE stpersonal
    INNER JOIN steducation ON steducation.stID = stpersonal.stID
    INNER JOIN staddress ON staddress.stID = stpersonal.stID
 SET stpersonal.stname = @stname,
    stpersonal.stdateofbirth = @stdateofbirth,
    stpersonal.stgender = @stgender,
    steducation.stcollege = @stcollege,
    steducation.stgradyear = @stgradyear,
    staddress.stAddress = @stAddress
 WHERE stpersonal.stID = @ID
```